What did 1935 U.S. Democrats believe?
I picked up a copy of Sinclair Lewis' 1935 fiction work It Can't Happen Here.  This copy (printed in 2014) boasts that it "is a shockingly prescient novel that remains as fresh and contemporary as today's news."  In general, the book is an alternate history in which a fascist dictator takes over the U.S. like what happened in Germany and Italy at about the same time.
Given that most sources describe fascism as a far-right phenomenon, I was prepared for this to be an anti-conservative rant.  But I was surprised to read that Buzz Windrip, the dicatator-to-be, was a Democrat.  Which leads to the question...  How many of these values would have aligned with Democrat ideology in 1935 in the US?
In short, Windrip advocates (this is my paraphrase; original text is quoted below).

unprecedented "big" government control over finances, labor, religion.
strong support for personal property rights, strong opposition to Communism.
broad anti-semitism
universal basic income for all, but also limits on maximum allowed income
a very strong military and preference for opening military conflicts for economic gain
revocation of voting rights for black people
requiring women to stay at home as homemakers
Unfettered rights to the Executive branch

Were any of these common Democrat values in 1935?

(1) All finance in the country, including banking, insurance, stocks and bonds and mortgages, shall be under the absolute control of a Federal Central Bank, owned by the government and conducted by a Board appointed by the President, which Board shall, without need of recourse to Congress for legislative authorization, be empowered to make all regulations governing finance. Thereafter, as soon as may be practicable, this said Board shall consider the nationalization and government-ownership, for the Profit of the Whole People, of all mines, oilfields, water power, public utilities, transportation, and communication.


(2) The President shall appoint a commission, equally divided between manual workers, employers, and representatives of the Public, to determine which Labor Unions are qualified to represent the Workers; and report to the Executive, for legal action, all pretended labor organizations, whether "Company Unions," or "Red Unions," controlled by Communists and the so-called "Third International." The duly recognized Unions shall be constituted Bureaus of the Government, with power of decision in all labor disputes. Later, the same investigation and official recognition shall be extended to farm organizations. In this elevation of the position of the Worker, it shall be emphasized that the League of Forgotten Men is the chief bulwark against the menace of destructive and un-American Radicalism.


(3) In contradistinction to the doctrines of Red Radicals, with their felonious expropriation of the arduously acquired possessions which insure to aged persons their security, this League and Party will guarantee Private Initiative and the Right to Private Property for all time.


(4) Believing that only under God Almighty, to Whom we render all homage, do we Americans hold our vast Power, we shall guarantee to all persons absolute freedom of religious worship, provided, however, that no atheist, agnostic, believer in Black Magic, nor any Jew who shall refuse to swear allegiance to the New Testament, nor any person of any faith who refuses to take the Pledge to the Flag, shall be permitted to hold any public office or to practice as a teacher, professor, lawyer, judge, or as a physician, except in the category of Obstetrics.


(5) Annual net income per person shall be limited to $500,000. No accumulated fortune may at any one time exceed $3,000,000 per person. No one person shall, during his entire lifetime, be permitted to retain an inheritance or various inheritances in total exceeding $2,000,000. All incomes or estates in excess of the sums named shall be seized by the Federal Government for use in Relief and in Administrative expenses.


(6) Profit shall be taken out of War by seizing all dividends over and above 6 per cent that shall be received from the manufacture, distribution, or sale, during Wartime, of all arms, munitions, aircraft, ships, tanks, and all other things directly applicable to warfare, as well as from food, textiles, and all other supplies furnished to the American or to any allied army.


(7) Our armaments and the size of our military and naval establishments shall be consistently enlarged until they shall equal, but—since this country has no desire for foreign conquest of any kind—not surpass, in every branch of the forces of defense, the martial strength of any other single country or empire in the world. Upon inauguration, this League and Party shall make this its first obligation, together with the issuance of a firm proclamation to all nations of the world that our armed forces are to be maintained solely for the purpose of insuring world peace and amity.


(8) Congress shall have the sole right to issue money and immediately upon our inauguration it shall at least double the present supply of money, in order to facilitate the fluidity of credit.


(9) We cannot too strongly condemn the un-Christian attitude of certain otherwise progressive nations in their discriminations against the Jews, who have been among the strongest supporters of the League, and who will continue to prosper and to be recognized as fully Americanized, though only so long as they continue to support our ideals.


(10) All Negroes shall be prohibited from voting, holding public office, practicing law, medicine, or teaching in any class above the grade of grammar school, and they shall be taxed 100 per cent of all sums in excess of $10,000 per family per year which they may earn or in any other manner receive. In order, however, to give the most sympathetic aid possible to all Negroes who comprehend their proper and valuable place in society, all such colored persons, male or female, as can prove that they have devoted not less than forty-five years to such suitable tasks as domestic service, agricultural labor, and common labor in industries, shall at the age of sixty-five be permitted to appear before a special Board, composed entirely of white persons, and upon proof that while employed they have never been idle except through sickness, they shall be recommended for pensions not to exceed the sum of $500.00 per person per year, nor to exceed $700.00 per family. Negroes shall, by definition, be persons with at least one sixteenth colored blood.


(11) Far from opposing such high-minded and economically sound methods of the relief of poverty, unemployment, and old age as the epic plan of the Hon. Upton Sinclair, the "Share the Wealth" and "Every Man a King" proposals of the late Hon. Huey Long to assure every family $5000 a year, the Townsend plan, the Utopian plan, Technocracy, and all competent schemes of unemployment insurance, a Commission shall immediately be appointed by the New Administration to study, reconcile, and recommend for immediate adoption the best features in these several plans for Social Security, and the Hon. Messrs. Sinclair, Townsend, Eugene Reed, and Howard Scott are herewith invited to in every way advise and collaborate with that Commission.


(12) All women now employed shall, as rapidly as possible, except in such peculiarly feminine spheres of activity as nursing and beauty parlors, be assisted to return to their incomparably sacred duties as home-makers and as mothers of strong, honorable future Citizens of the Commonwealth.


(13) Any person advocating Communism, Socialism, or Anarchism, advocating refusal to enlist in case of war, or advocating alliance with Russia in any war whatsoever, shall be subject to trial for high treason, with a minimum penalty of twenty years at hard labor in prison, and a maximum of death on the gallows, or other form of execution which the judges may find convenient.


(14) All bonuses promised to former soldiers of any war in which America has ever engaged shall be immediately paid in full, in cash, and in all cases of veterans with incomes of less than $5,000.00 a year, the formerly promised sums shall be doubled.


(15) Congress shall, immediately upon our inauguration, initiate amendments to the Constitution providing (a), that the President shall have the authority to institute and execute all necessary measures for the conduct of the government during this critical epoch; (b), that Congress shall serve only in an advisory capacity, calling to the attention of the President and his aides and Cabinet any needed legislation, but not acting upon same until authorized by the President so to act; and (c), that the Supreme Court shall immediately have removed from its jurisdiction the power to negate, by ruling them to be unconstitutional or by any other judicial action, any or all acts of the President, his duly appointed aides, or Congress.


Addendum: It shall be strictly understood that, as the League of Forgotten Men and the Democratic Party, as now constituted, have no purpose nor desire to carry out any measure that shall not unqualifiedly meet with the desire of the majority of voters in these United States, the League and Party regard none of the above fifteen points as obligatory and unmodifiable except No. 15, and upon the others they will act or refrain from acting in accordance with the general desire of the Public, who shall under the new régime be again granted an individual freedom of which they have been deprived by the harsh and restrictive economic measures of former administrations, both Republican and Democratic.


Please see, Cutoff between Politics and History

There's (pedanticly) no such thing as "Democrat Party", and (less pedanticly) no such thing as "Democrat Values".

The 1936 Democratic party platform can be read here

Both parties are (and always have been) coalitions. I think JustCal has the right approach, although I'd be vaguely curious to know how much party platforms align with any other test of what a party  "believes"  There is an interesting research opportunity here.   Might also be interesting to explore how each plank was represented in politics at the time.  Which parties/candidates were for federally controlled banking? and so on for each bullet point.

This question perhaps suffers from a misapprehension that US political parties are composed of people with a single unified monolithic belief system. I think that has to be cleared up first, before we can continue. In fact, for the 2 major parties that has never been the case, and systemically can't be the case.
Duverger's Law says that the steady-state condition of a political system that has only one winner is two parties. Few people will ever support any weaker parties, because mathematically only the top two have any chance of winning.
The problem is politics among large groups of people don't actually work that way. Different people not only have different values, but they also weigh them far differently. Some people vote on abortion. Some people vote their religion. Some people vote for their economic views. Some people vote based on bigotry.
We know this because elsewhere without that single-winner limitation, people naturally organize themselves into far more parties than this. The German Parliament currently has 10 different parties1, and 5 independents. Israel's contains 19 parties and 3 independents. In both bodies, these parties organize into a "governing" coalition (a group of parties with most of the seats), and Opposition. Sometimes the "Government" coalition contains some parties with starkly different values from each other, and the "Opposition" pretty much always does.
We people of the USA aren't a different species. However, since our system forces 2 parties, the natural factions are hidden inside the parties. Effectively, under a parliamentary system the voters chose their parties, then the parties get together in smoke-filled rooms and decide which ones will get to be "Government" Coalition and which ones have to be Opposition.
Under the US system, voters have factions they support that are similar to Parliamentary parties, who form coalitions that in the US we call "parties". The politicians representing the factions decide before the election what party coalition they will vote with, and then the voters looking at that decide on election day which party coalition they want to be Government and which will have to be the opposition.2
Another under-appreciated facet of this system is that the two major parties do not in fact as a whole have lasting coherent "values". Rather they are an amalgam of the factions/wings that they happen to contain today. These faction alignments don't change very quickly, but when they do we call them "party realignment"s, and the new alliances are referred to as a "Party System". We are currently operating under the Sixth Party System (or Possibly Seventh Party System, depending on who you ask. The "systems" are much easier to identify after they have ended).
Here's a nice chart that attempts to show the changes in the Party Systems based on which factions jumped parties. Note that the big fat "Southern Strategy" arrow down near the bottom is a polite way of saying "White Supremacists".


With this established, we can go back to the question now knowing to ask, What were the political factions/wings in 1935, and which parties were they aligned with?
1935 was just past the (1932) beginning of the Fifth Party System, often called The New Deal Era. The Parties and their factions during this time were essentially:
Democratic Party

Labor Unions
Blue-collar workers
racial and religious minorities
White Southerners (notably White Supremacists with a historic antipathy for the Republican Party)
Intellectuals

Republican Party

Business Interests
White Collar and Wealthy Protestants
(What are now known as) Libertarians

You may note that this doesn't seem to leave many voters for the Republicans, and you'd be right. The Democratic Party was electorally dominant during this period.
You may also note that White Supremacists and racial and religious minorities don't seem like groups that would be happy in a party coalition together, and you'd be right again. In fact what eventually broke up the New Deal coalition (starting the 5th Party System) was White Supremacists during the Civil Rights era fleeing the now minority-filled Democratic party like it was a newly desegregated swimming pool.

So now its time to ask, What does any of this have to say about our fictional "Buzz Windrip"? How normal of a Democrat would he have been?
I think the big clue in there is the mention of Huey P Long. Long was a Populist politician from Louisiana often derided at the time as a Fascist or compared to Hitler (by both people who were for and against those things). He was quite possibly preparing for a run in the Democratic Primary against FDR when he was assassinated over a gerrymandering dispute in 1935.
Long's Share Our Wealth plan included hard limits on personal wealth, so that much is similar. However, he didn't care much about race or religion. The White Supremacy faction of the Democratic Party did care about those things, of course. Southern Conservatives would also have been more inclined to look favorably on rolling back women's role in society, and promoting Protestant Christianity. Long did have a lot of ideas about government involvement in both labor disputes and in the economy in general that horrified Libertarians.
What I think we have here with Lewis is someone who saw the rise of right-wing populists in Europe, and felt (quite reasonably) like there's no good reason that couldn't happen here. Humans are human everywhere after all. To illustrate the point, he made himself a fictional political Frankenstein's monster out of a recent real populist politician and some of the less savory far-right wings that happened to reside in the Democratic Party at the time.

1 - Its debatable how "independent" the CDU and the CSU are. The fact that its this complicated kind of makes my point though.
2 - An argument could be made that this is more open and Democratic.

Suggestion: Add "Old money aristocrats" to the democrat list, and "petite bourgeoisie" to the republican list. FDR was an aristocrat, for example. They were a very important social group that should not be omitted.

@AstorFlorida - The latter is not a term commonly used to describe a US voting bloc historically, and is essentially just describing 2 blocs already listed. The former is simply not accurate. FDR came from a family that included Republican presidents on both sides. His father was a "Burbon Democrat", but that faction had long since died out and wandered off to join the Republicans by 1935. They shared no ideology with FDR. FDR himself was a political protege of Woodrow Wilson who was a former History professor (and thus fair to say an "Intellectual").

Is it really true that other systems don't follow Duverger's Law?  It seems to me they all end up with two factions at the end; even in a parliamentary system you get the unrelated ideologies forming coalitions.  I don't see how that's all that much different than in the US, where which ideologies 'belong' to which party changes over time.  In the UK you had the LibDems and the Conservatives form the Cameron-Clegg Coalition, and in the US you have the Evangelicals and the Libertarians forming the Republican party.  In both, minor parties either join up or have their issues 'stolen'.

There are seven parliamentary parties ("Fraktionen"): BSW, Linke, Greens, SPD, Union (CDU/CSU), FDP, AfD. Note that the last three entries are "Fraktionslose": One member who was voted into Parliament via the AfD but never joined the parliamentary group, one from the SSW (a Schleswig-Holstein only party, but parties with less than 3 members are not officially recognized in German parliament), and 5 who were voted into Parliament without being part of any party at all ("Parteilose"). Interesting to note that even here, many parties aren't that "monolithic" in their beliefs either.
